# starting on web development project

Tags: php, project

I am looking to start a web development project. I thought about using a  reference as a guideline for the project.
My question,whether I am allowed to use the reference and use that or should I use my own code/script?

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you talking about stealing code from others?

Comment: that is exactly what he means.. you can steal codes from others (in the name of reference) as long as the original writers do not make a case of plagiarism against you.. i would suggest to learn first and then go for copying from others..

Comment: 1) It's unclear what you're asking. 2) Even if it would be clearer, this doesn't sound like a question on-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: example:i look for the tutorial and i use that for my project,i'm afraid is allowed or not.

Answer (score 2):

It is depends to License and permission. For example Open Source, YES, you can modify the code. Read the License and permission first before you copying someone code. If you found some code and didn't found any License on it, contact the writer whether you are allowed to modify his code or not. If you didn't find any License and can not contact the author. Do not modify the code and mark it as your project. Sometime this is can lead you into serious copyright problem.

> Because open source code is publicly accessible, students can learn to make better software by studying what others have written. They can also share their work with others, inviting comment and critique.

You can read this as your reference : http://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source